# MVC3 Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm not new to ASP.NET MVC but I have a really strange issue that I haven't been able to solve. I've checked most other related queries on SO and further afield but I haven't yet found a solution. I have a really simple ASP.NET MVC 3 application running under Cassini which was working fine until I added log4net logging. I've since removed all the references to log4net to try and get it back but I always get the error:

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed blah...

This is the result, no matter which url is requested.

The application still has the original HomeController, Index.cshtml etc and the default route from the standard 'out-of-the-box' Visual Studio 2010 template.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

I've checked and double-checked that there is no file missing (e.g. a css or js file) thats required and another issue which prevents me from moving forward on this issue is that no breakpoints are hit when trying to debug it. In fact, if I put a breakpoint on the first line in the Application_Start method, and start debugging, the breakpoint is not hit at all and a second breakpoint appears (see the image below)!

[image: Only the first breakpoint was actually inserted]

This happens even if I do a clean and rebuild.
I've tried using Phil Haacks Route Debugger but still get the same error and the fact that the Application_Start breakpoint is not being hit makes me suspect my web.config. I've checked it several times and in fact replaced it with a web.config from my hosted site where the application is running ok, but still get the same result on my development setup.
I've checked there is no StartUp page in the properties.
I want to add some more functionality and be able to debug it before deploying to my hosted site but this is stopping me.

Has anyone come across breakpoints being added when you start debugging? Considering the symptoms, where would you start looking for the root of the problem?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning out your Temporary Internet Files? Shut down VS, delete your \bin and \obj folders as well. Then open everything back up and rebuild.

Comment: Yeah, just tried that - same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it, so for those who might trip over this one, I've noted the reason why below. However, what might be of more value was my approach to find the issue in the face of no debugging or tracing available. As it is still a small site I decided to create another standard 'out-of-the-box' MVC 3 application and manually compare files. There appeared to be no difference between files but while going through this exercise I noticed that in the problem application, the Global.asax files were sitting in the Views folder! I must have inadvertantly moved them - it wasn't immediately obvious because the Views folder was always expanded and glancing at it, would appear that the Global.asax files were in the right place because they are normally immediately below the Views folder (just not indented as they are when inside the Views folder).

Anyway, problem caused by me but did cause some weird behaviour!